# How to customize the appearance of the taskbar window?

Tags: front-end, customization, linux, version-11.3, version-10.4

When a Running notebook in v10.4 is minimalized, on the taskbar it reads `Running... Untitled-1...`. For v11.3 it reads `Untitled-1 * (Running)...`

[image]

How can I make this appearance of v11.3 be the same as it is in v10.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any public interface to change this but you can play with:

```
With[{nb := EvaluationNotebook[], CV = CurrentValue}
 , SetOptions[$FrontEndSession
   , CellProlog :> (
       CV[nb, {TaggingRules, "titleCache"}] = CV[nb, WindowTitle]
     ; CV[nb, WindowTitle] = "Running... " <> AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowTitle]
     )
   , CellEpilog :> (
       CV[nb, WindowTitle] = CV[nb, {TaggingRules, "titleCache"}]
     )
   ]
]
```

Notice that the native "Running..." postfix is still there, ugly but will not be visible on a taskbar.

Additional problem that `CellProlog` and Epilog may already be set :/

Comment: Looks cool. Is there a way to make it default for all v11.3 notebooks, without evaluating your code every time?

Comment: @corey979 change `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd`.